# creating onclick mouse event for column header

Tags: c#

I have a windows form with 6 column headers.I want to create a line chart when a specific column header is clicked.

Can anyone tell me how to iterate over each column header and pass the list for creating line chart?

Comment: Is this for a DataGridView?

Comment: yes it is for DataGridView

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I tried the code but for the function                                                               private void DataGridView1_OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {} it is showing type or namespace name could not be found for DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs .Why so?

Comment: You have to show us more of your code.  Edit the question, don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView has an event `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` which you can use. If the namespace can't be found, make sure that there's

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

in your code behind class.